# Work queue with complex select and long processing: Ensuring concurrency

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, locking, concurrency, queue

I have a queue table from which worker processes claim records, one at a time. It is crucial that no two workers claim same item to process.

Normally this kind of thing is done with `select top (1) ... with (updlock, rowlock, readpast)`.
This works as expected and provides great concurrency when there is a covering index, but for this particular query the `where` condition is complex, depends on the time of the day and on presence of records in other tables (`where exists(...)`), and is followed by an `order by` of similar nastiness, so it cannot be covered by a single index or an indexed view.

In this situation the `select top (1)` puts the `updlock` on all rows that match the `where`, not just the first one, which leads to one worker winning the job and all the others waiting (or falsely reporting that there were no more rows to process).

While this does not lead to any errors, the concurrency is not great. The problem is that record selection is quite cheap, but record processing is very expensive. So the other workers sit there doing nothing for seconds.

In an attempt to fix this concurrency issue [I came up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147640) with the following solution for the job selection (error handling removed for clarity):

```
exec sp_getapplock N'Pick a Job', 'Update';

declare @will_lock_that int;
select top (1) @will_lock_that = row_id from the_table with(readpast) where... order by...;

declare @locked int;
select @locked = row_id from the_table with(updlock, rowlock, holdlock) where row_id = @will_lock_that;

exec sp_releaseapplock N'Pick a Job';
```

The idea was that:

- The applock makes sure only one process at a time will be picking a job. This is okay because picking a job is cheap.
  The applock will be released very quickly, letting the other workers pick their jobs, while the original worker will be processing the item, having released the applock.
- The first `select` statement will have to fetch all rows matching the `where` condition, as described above, but this time it will not put any persistent locks on them. The shared locks will be released as soon as the `select` returns.
- The `readpast` in that `select` will skip over any rows already being processed, because they are locked with `updlock`s.
- The locking hints in the second `select` will hide the row from the first, `readpast`-enabled `select` performed by others.

Of course this did not work. `readpast` did not try to skip over the `updlock`ed rows. Instead it would wait for the first encountered locked row to be released. Changing the `updlock` to `xlock` in the second query does not change this, neither does making an actual update to the row.
The only way to make the `readpast` skip over rows seems to be adding a locking hint to the `readpast` query itself (e.g. `with(readpast, updlock)`) - but that fails the original purpose, because now all rows will again be locked with `updlock`.

**Is there a way to solve this concurrency problem** without using manual locks? (By manual locks I mean updating a special field in the row to 'Locked', outside of a transaction for others to see, and then updating it back when processing is finished.)

I cannot use the [locking by deletion](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/), too, because the row must stay in the same table, and only few of its fields will change after processing.

Comment: We solve this problem with a UserID column in the record. If the record has a UserID then someone is working on it. It works great for high-concurrency and we don't have to use a bunch of hints.

Comment: We're doing similar thing with @JNK, but just with status field (0 for waiting, 1 being handled etc.) and then there's no need for leaving locks to the table.

Comment: To be more specific, the methods in Remus' blog post are not really intended for letting users pick their own records - they are record delivery systems. If you're going to allow user autonomy it's a lot easier to track it as an attribute of the row.

Comment: @JNK There are two problems with this kind of locking - 1) it needs to be done outside of the transaction, so it must be taken out of the stored procedure that does the job and put on the client side, which breaks incapsulation and trusts the client too much, and 2) when the client closes unexpectedly the row remains permanently locked, so there needs to be a watch mechanism to unlock them that would be clever enough to not give false positives and yet unlock promptly. Also there is no choosing on the client side, the client must be happy with the row the system thinks it should take.

Comment: You could determine the row to be selected under snapshot isolation in a separate transaction. Then, you start a new tran, lock that row and validate that it is still available for processing. If not, you retry. That should get rid of almost all locking.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned you could not use 'locking by deletion' because the row must stay in the table. The code example below does use it, but only after creating a global queue first and populating it. It then uses the 'locking by deletion' for the ##Queue table rather than the table you're working with.

```
USE master
GO

    -- 1. Create a Stored Procedure that creates the Queue and populates it based on the criteria you have.
    --      (this doesn't have to be a Stored Procedure, but can also be run via some other method to populate the queue.)
    --      (also update 'DatabaseName.SchemaName.the_table' to be the name of your table.)

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master.dbo.sysobjects o WHERE o.xtype IN ('P') AND o.id = object_id('master.dbo.CreateQueue'))
    DROP PROC CreateQueue
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.CreateQueue
    AS
    BEGIN
        IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb.dbo.##Queue') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE ##Queue

        SELECT * INTO ##Queue FROM DatabaseName.SchemaName.the_table WHERE <replace with your criteria> 
    END
    GO

    -- 2. Execute the SP above or use the code some other way to create the ##Queue

    -- 3. Copy the code below and run it via multiple processes if you like, as there should not be concurrency issues.
    WHILE 1 = 1
        BEGIN
            DELETE TOP ( 1 )
                    ##Queue WITH ( READPAST )
            OUTPUT  Deleted.*
                    INTO #RowToProcess
            IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0 
                BEGIN
                    --Place logic here to work with the row...
                    DELETE  FROM #RowToProcess
                END
            ELSE
                BREAK
        END
```